# How to find all my stockpiles?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there any way to find all the stockpiles I created, other than by pressing k and navigating around all the tiles that represent stockpiles? (Some stockpiles are adjacent to each other by mistake, so I actually need to touch each square to see if there's a stockpile I missed.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stockpiles count as rooms, so they are listed under the <kbd>R</kbd>ooms designation.

From here, you should have the option to <kbd>z</kbd>oom to the stockpile, to find where you placed them.